# How to make mosquitto_sub print ip address of publisher of particular message

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

How to make mosquitto_sub print ip address of publisher of particular message:

```
$ mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t "#" -u "user" -P "pass" -v

home/sensor/esp1/Temperature 21.2
home/sensor/esp1/Humidity 46.0
```

If there is way to show ip adress of publisher which sends this message?

Answer (score 1):

You can not.

There is no information about the publisher in a MQTT message, so the information is just not available unless you choose to encode it in the actual payload.

A MQTT message just contains the topic, the payload and some flags to show QOS and retained status and that is all